VBA, ADO and SharePoint list : retrieving columns of type Person
I am working with VBA and ADODB to retrieve the content of SharePoint lists.
It works well but for some reason, I can't retrieve columns of type Person.
I am absolutely certain these exist in the list.
But even if I select the field by its name instead of *, I still get no result (I explicitly search for it 'If fieldName = "ColumnOfTypePersonName"' but no dice...).
Does anyone here can explain why ?
Here is my code:
    Dim Conn As Object
    Dim Rec_Set As Object
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fieldName As String
    Dim fieldValue As Variant
    
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rec_Set = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set resultTable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                            "DATABASE=" & "mySharePointURL;" & _
                            "LIST={listGuid};"
        .Open
    End With
    
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [MyListName];"
    
    With Rec_Set
        If .State = 1 Then .Close
        
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = Sql
        .Open
    
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                fieldName = .Fields(i).Name
                fieldValue = .Fields(i).Value
                If fieldName = "ColumnOfTypePersonName" Then
                    MsgBox fieldValue 'Never hit!
                End If
                resultTable.Add fieldName, fieldValue
            Next i
        End If
    
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set Rec_Set = Nothing


Works for me using the guid where you have MyListName  Are you sure you're looking for the correct field name?  Have you tried just listing out all of the field names from the recordset?

@TimWilliams Yes I am sure. I even selected the field based on its name instead of the * and it is still not retrieved. And as you can see with the line If fieldName = "ColumnOfTypePersonName" Then  --> I am explicitely searching for it.

If you Debug.Print fieldName, fieldValue doall the other fields show up apart from those of type Person?

Hi Tim, yes, I do. Moreover, I added a new "normal" field to make sure I can see it, with a value I set in the grid, and I can retrieve it no problem.

I have no idea why my results are different from yours.  Googling around this topic there's not much to go on.

Well, thanks for taking a look, Tim!

@TimWilliams just to be sure, were you telling me you tried to retrieve the content of a list using the same ADO mechanism and you actually CAN get the content of a column of type Person?

Yes - all columns including the "person"-type column were retrieved.

Hey @TimWilliams it seems you are right : I can retrieve a person column's content when it's set to not enable multi people selection. Could you please confirm whether you also can retrieve a column's content when it's not multi selection but you can't when it's multiple selection allowed?

Yes I can confirm that - after switching to multi-select my "Person" field was no longer selectable via ADO

Well, that sucks but now I understand the problem. Thanks again for taking the time @TimWilliams
